# Google static map on C# .net 4.0 doesn't show markers and path

Tags: c#, static, maps, twebbrowser, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to draw a path and markers using C# and google static map. I'm creating the url for the map, which includes one marker and a path. I'm using this line in order to show the map:

```
MapWebBrowser.Navigate(url);
```

The map is loading without the markers and the path.

When I use any other browser (chrome, IE) with the same URL I get the desired result - markers and path are shown.

Example URL for static map:

```
string urlCompressed = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyDvznVMd7qtCu1DIgndYeGq2LgsYtmBHC8&path=weight:2|32.0790,34.80427|32.08148,34.81|32.08148,34.80427&markers=32.08148,34.80427&zoom=14&scale=2&size=673x520&maptype=roadmap&format=png");

MapWebBrowser.Navigate(urlCompressed);
```

When I browse to this `url` in chrome it works fine. When I try it in the app it shows another location and no markers or path.

Please help, any clue will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found what went wrong:
The map size was bigger than my webbrowser size. This caused the center of the map (and the markers) to be outside of the webbrowser view.
I just had to fit the map size to the webbrowser size and it worked.